# Trouble getting Json.Net to deserialize to a custom object

Tags: visual-studio-2013, json.net

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out why JSON.Net is unable to deserialize my JSON data into a custom object. I suspect its something with my Class. I'm not getting any errors, but when I put a break in the code and check the object after the line where it's created there is nothing inside the object. I've verified that the variable strBackupInfo does contain the JSON data.

Below is the JSON data I'm working with

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2014-06-26T16:42:40.041-04:00",
        "params": {
            "username": "test-account",
            "incComputerCount": "true"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "totalCount": 1,
        "users": [
            {
                "userId": 5,
                "userUid": "7f637e0e9b5a7909",
                "status": "Active",
                "username": "test-account",
                "email": "test-account@corp.net",
                "firstName": "",
                "lastName": "",
                "quotaInBytes": -1,
                "orgId": 3,
                "orgUid": "551317080886150419",
                "orgName": "MiWorkspace",
                "active": true,
                "blocked": false,
                "emailPromo": true,
                "invited": false,
                "orgType": "ENTERPRISE",
                "usernameIsAnEmail": false,
                "creationDate": "2012-10-15T13:13:51.353-04:00",
                "modificationDate": "2014-03-05T15:08:38.637-05:00",
                "passwordReset": false,
                "computerCount": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are the custom classes I created from the JSON data:

```
Public Class JSONBackupInfo
    Public Property username() As String
        Get
            Return m_username
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_username = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_username As String
    Public Property incComputerCount() As String
        Get
            Return m_incComputerCount
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_incComputerCount = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_incComputerCount As String
End Class

Public Class Metadata
    Public Property timestamp() As String
        Get
            Return m_timestamp
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_timestamp = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_timestamp As String
    Public Property params() As JSONBackupInfo

        Get
            Return m_params
        End Get
        Set(value As JSONBackupInfo)
            m_params = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_params As JSONBackupInfo
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property userId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_userId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_userId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_userId As Integer
    Public Property userUid() As String
        Get
            Return m_userUid
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_userUid = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_userUid As String
    Public Property status() As String
        Get
            Return m_status
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_status = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_status As String
    Public Property username() As String
        Get
            Return m_username
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_username = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_username As String
    Public Property email() As String
        Get
            Return m_email
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_email = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_email As String
    Public Property firstName() As String
        Get
            Return m_firstName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_firstName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_firstName As String
    Public Property lastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_lastName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_lastName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_lastName As String
    Public Property quotaInBytes() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_quotaInBytes
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_quotaInBytes = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_quotaInBytes As Integer
    Public Property orgId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_orgId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_orgId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_orgId As Integer
    Public Property orgUid() As String
        Get
            Return m_orgUid
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_orgUid = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_orgUid As String
    Public Property orgName() As String
        Get
            Return m_orgName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_orgName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_orgName As String
    Public Property active() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_active
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_active = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_active As Boolean
    Public Property blocked() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_blocked
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_blocked = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_blocked As Boolean
    Public Property emailPromo() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_emailPromo
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_emailPromo = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_emailPromo As Boolean
    Public Property invited() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_invited
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_invited = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_invited As Boolean
    Public Property orgType() As String
        Get
            Return m_orgType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_orgType = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_orgType As String
    Public Property usernameIsAnEmail() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_usernameIsAnEmail
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_usernameIsAnEmail = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_usernameIsAnEmail As Boolean
    Public Property creationDate() As String
        Get
            Return m_creationDate
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_creationDate = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_creationDate As String
    Public Property modificationDate() As String
        Get
            Return m_modificationDate
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_modificationDate = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_modificationDate As String
    Public Property passwordReset() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_passwordReset
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_passwordReset = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_passwordReset As Boolean
    Public Property computerCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_computerCount
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_computerCount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_computerCount As Integer
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property totalCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_totalCount
        End Geta
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_totalCount = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_totalCount As Integer
    Public Property users() As List(Of User)
        Get
            Return m_users
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of User))
            m_users = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_users As List(Of User)
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property metadata() As Metadata
        Get
            Return m_metadata
        End Get
        Set(value As Metadata)
            m_metadata = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_metadata As Metadata
    Public Property data() As Data
        Get
            Return m_data
        End Get
        Set(value As Data)
            m_data = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_data As Data
End Class
```

And here is my code:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim strBackupInfo As String


        Try
            ' Create the web request 
            For Each strUser As String In txtBackupUsers.Text.Split(vbNewLine)

                request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("UR"), HttpWebRequest)

                ' Add authentication to request  
                request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(HIDDEN)

                ' Get response  
                response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

                ' Get the response stream into a reader  
                reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

                ' Console application output  
                strBackupInfo = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString
                txtBackupResults.Text = strBackupInfo


                Dim BackupObject As JSONBackupInfo = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of JSONBackupInfo)(strBackupInfo)

            Next
        Finally
            If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty object because you are deserializing the JSON into the wrong class.  You should be deserializing into your `RootObject` class, not `JSONBackupInfo`.

```
Dim BackupObject As RootObject = _
          New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of RootObject)(strBackupInfo)
```

Note also, your question is tagged as `Json.Net`, but it appears you are using the `JavaScriptSerializer` from the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly, which is not part of Json.Net.  Depending on your needs, the JavaScriptSerializer may or may not work for you, but if you intended to use Json.Net then you should be using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` instead.

```
Dim BackupObject As RootObject = _
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(strBackupInfo)
```